# WPF bind controls to static object[] array data (.NET 4.5)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a static object[] array (500+ items) that is changed every second and many controls that need to display the data contained in this array. I need this array to be static because it's used in many other classes.

Is it possible to implement such bind in .NET 4.5? I'm trying the code below without success (based on http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/28/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-9-binding-to-static-properties/ ). I get a 'Playback.Control' does not implement interface member 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' error on compile

```
public class Control : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
    public static void RaiseChangeEvent(string propName)
    {
        EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> handler = StaticPropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        handler(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    private static int _playposition;
    public static int PlayPosition { get { return _playposition; } set { if (_playposition == value) return; _playposition = value; RaiseChangeEvent("PlayPosition"); } }

    public static DataTable JobData { get; private set; }

    private static Object[] _currentdata;
    public static Object[] CurrentData { get { return _currentdata; } set { if (_currentdata == value) return; _currentdata = value; RaiseChangeEvent("CurrentData"); } }

    private static Object[] _previousdata;
    public static Object[] PreviousData { get { return _previousdata; } set { if (_previousdata == value) return; _previousdata = value; RaiseChangeEvent("PreviousData"); } }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you link to is a bit confusing, and I suspect you've mixed up the two approaches. Looking at the author's dropbox project, there seems to be two approaches - one class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and another that *doesn't* (Repository.cs). The latter uses the StaticPropertyChanged event approach that I think you are trying to use. I guess you just need to change your code so that it doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but check the author's dropbox code just to be sure.

Comment: Thank you! Removing the INotifyPropertyChanged solved everything...I was so into it that I missed the most basic detail...